# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'collidepoint'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I recently started with python and pygame. my first project is to create a game where you have to click on blocks that randomly appear on the screen. After hours of research and problem solving i haven't come up with a solution. I guess I'm not that good at customizing other answers to my code. Here's the code:

```
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()

game_width = 800
game_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((game_width, game_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Click It')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, red)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(2)
    game_loop()

def failed():
    message_diplay('You Failed')

def game_loop():
    thing_height = 100
    thing_width = 100
    thing_startx = random.randrange(0, game_width-thing_width)
    thing_starty = random.randrange(0, game_height-thing_height)
    rectangle = (thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height)

    def things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color):
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, color, [thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh])

    failed = False
    while not failed:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height, blue )

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                click = rectangle.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())

                if click == 1:
                    print ('Clicked!!')

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a tuple and are trying to use the method `collidepoint` (which tuples don't have). You're probably intending to use a [`Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect) object instead, so change the line

```
rectangle = (thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height)
```

to

```
rectangle = pygame.Rect(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height)
```

Comment: btw: you could add link to `pygame.Rect` doc.

Comment: @furas That's right, I'll add it in. Thanks!